# Creating a NSThread Game Loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, game-loop

Im trying to create a NSThread game loop, i have some of the time been able to get a successful 57 FPS.

Some of the time my fps goes up to some ridiculice number.

I dont understand how its happening.

I check how long since the last loop and if it was to quick, sleep the thread for that much time.

This is not always happening, it sometimes escapes the if check on the speed and does the loop way to fast.

Any comments would mean alot.

Also where am i suposed to 'Tick' ?

```
   - (void)gameLoop{
   //gameIsRunning is set to TRUE in viewDidLoad
   while (gameIsRunnning){
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //Get Current date
    NSDate *curTime = [NSDate date];

    //Time since last loop and vurrent date;
    NSTimeInterval timePassed_ms = [curTime timeIntervalSinceDate:old_date];// * 1000.0;

    NSLog(@"***************");

    //Cout the time interval
    NSLog(@"Loop Time %f",timePassed_ms);

    //Check if the loop was to fast and sleep for long enough to make up for about 60 FPS
    if (timePassed_ms < 1.0/60) {
        double timeToSleep = timePassed_ms - (1.0/60);
        timeToSleep = timeToSleep*-1;
        NSLog(@"Sleep For %f",timeToSleep);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:timeToSleep];
    }

    //This new date is to try and check if after waiting the loop is taking the correct duration
    NSDate *newDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timePassed_after = [newDate timeIntervalSinceDate:curTime];// * 1000.0;

    //Make an fps out of this new time interval after wait
    double FPS = (1.0/timePassed_after);
    NSLog(@"FPS %f",FPS);
    NSLog(@"Adjusted Time %f",timePassed_after);

    NSLog(@"***************");

    //Reset olddate for next loop
    old_date = curTime;

    //Apparently this will capture touches and button events
    while(CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.002, TRUE) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);

    //A test on moving a ball to see how smooth it will be
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(moveBall) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

   [pool drain];

  } 

}
```

Comment: Other threads or even processes on your computer could affect this thread's timing. What else is going on in your app?

Comment: Just the method the move the ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on sleeping a thread because you can never be sure it will take the same amount of time.

So instead of making a thread sleep, do nothing with it, nothing at all (except of course with incrementing your fixed time step)

You will find you will have a much smoother Frame Rate then.

Also as a side note, don't use FPS as a performance indicator. Use the amount of time a single update has taken to be completed.

If you are aiming @ 60fps, your goal processing time should be 0.01666* seconds. In reality you should be able to increase your processing time to 0.02555* which is 40fps and there should be no noticable performance hit on the game

EDIT: I also noticed you are creating a new pool and draining everytime the update is hit, in my experiences the autorelease pools should be placed at higher levels such appDelegate. But I wouldn't take it any lower then the level creation(create)/release(drain), moving this further up will help with performance as well.

Comment: But how do i evenly increment my fixed time step in the thread? it will be just going as fast as it can. I cant see how incrementing the timeStamp in it will work. Wouldn't it just instantly go into the thousands?

Comment: You dont evenly increment it, you increase it by the time difference from the end of the Previous game time (it took to complete). Then after you've done your update (even if you do nothing) calculate how long that took and the next update is incremented by that. It will result in a much smoother Frame rate

Comment: Are you sure moving the pool up wont cause more lag because the the amount of objects in the pool? iv seen people push to even flush the pool and create new ones in the loop more then once.

Comment: If you are following proper memory management it won't be a problem. If you are creating too many objects either look at your design or manually release them. 

The Auto release pool is for all objects that are created with the autorelease flag. The drain forces all these objects (no longer in use) and ones that have been released to be destroyed. Basically you are creating a destroying various objects 60+ times a second

Comment: hoe many objects would you say your game would have at any one time? Around 1,000 ?

Comment: I still cannot wrap my head around how to move something biased of a timestamp. I get the time when the loop ends and when the next one starts, then i get the NSTimeInterval for that which might be 0.0810 or something. Are you saying i then do [self moveObject:0.0810];?

Comment: your objects that move should have a velocity vector to move. Your object update should update the based off the time.

Comment: Your update should be broken up as such

Compute Delta Method (the delta is the change of time since the last update)
Pass the Delta into the update methods.

Use the delta to increment your fixed Time Step when it reaches the threshold perform all updates on all objects

Answer (score 1):

I recommend switching to `CADisplayLink` API ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)).  It creates a timer that automatically fires as often as the display refreshes, without you having to figure out how long to sleep.  This will solve the problem about delivering "refresh" events to your code, but it will not solve all your problems.

Obviously, if your code can't finish in 1/60 seconds then you will not get 60 fps.  Make sure your game logic and physics is not tied to the video refresh rate.  Some people disagree whether `CADisplayLink` is the right thing to do.  However, the agreed alternative is to update as fast as the hardware permits.

Last year, I switched a rendering loop in a toy game I had to use a display link (Mac, not iOS).  I noticed a significant improvement in how "smooth" the game felt.  Your results may vary.

Here is one way to do it (semi-pseudocode, simplified):

```
- (void)update:(CADisplayLink *)link {
    now = gettime();
    while (gametime < now) {
        // Physics always updated at rate of 1/delta
        advanceframe();
        gametime += delta;
    }
    draw();
}
```

Comment: when it comes to games, using a fixed timestep is widely accepted method. It allows things like physics and timed events in games to become more deterministic.

It is also good practise as it allows you to break up your game logic from your physics and/or communication logic which in itself further improves performance and the ability to maintain the code

Comment: @CStreel: I wholeheartedly agree.  However, you cannot (easily) guarantee a fixed video update frequency, which is why I suggest decoupling the physics and game logic from the display update.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) gameLoop 
{

    NSAutoreleasePool* loopPool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    int loopCnt = 0;

    while ( isRunning ) {

    while(CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.002f, TRUE) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);

        [self draw];

        select(0, 0, 0, 0, &tm);

        if ( loopCnt > 20000 ) {      // 20000
            loopCnt = 0;
            [loopPool release];
            loopPool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
        }
        ++loopCnt;

        while(CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.002f, TRUE) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);

        }   

    [loopPool release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`timeIntervalSinceDate:` returns the interval in seconds, not milliseconds.

(I wanted to write this in a little comment, not in a real answer, but couldn't figure out how to do this...)